# __extends is not defined when running Mocha unit tests

Tags: typescript, mocha.js

When I try to run my unit tests, I get the following output

```
$ npm test

> @ test C:\workspace\project
> mocha -r ./testhook.ts app/**/*.spec.ts


C:\workspace\project\app\common\product\price.model.ts:92
export class Price extends AbstractPrice {
^
ReferenceError: __extends is not defined
```

`testhook.ts` contains:

```
require('ts-node').register({
    compilerOptions: {
        noEmitHelpers: false
    }
});
```

What can I do to resolve this error?

This is a nativescript-angular project. The contents of tsconfig.json are:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "noEmitHelpers": true,
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "lib": [
            "es6",
            "dom",
            "es2015",
            "es2015.iterable"
        ],
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "*": [
                "./node_modules/tns-core-modules/*",
                "./node_modules/*"
            ]
        }
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "platforms"
    ]
}
```

Update: I just found out that if I remove all generated .js files from the app folder, the tests run fine. Can anyone explain that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough information regarding your problem.
But you can play a little with other related options like `importHelpers` or
try switching the typescript code to use es6 style export:

```
class Price extends AbstractPrice {
}

export { Price };
```

Comment: What more information do you need? I can provide it.

I tried adding `importHelpers: true, target: "es6"` to testhook.ts, but it changes nothing. It almost feels as if whatever I do in that file is simply ignored...

Comment: did you try the es6 style export?

Comment: You need to create a minimal solution that breaks and list all of the files

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided much information about your setup, but I am wondering if you are hitting [this bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17192)

> This causes a valid typescript file to fail, as functions like __extend will be undefined.

Please make sure you are using TypeScript 2.7 or higher.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip. However, I'm running 2.7.1, so that can't be the issue: `$ ts-node -v
ts-node v4.1.0
node v8.9.1
typescript v2.7.1`

Comment: I've added some more info about the setup if that helps

Comment: Try simplifying things. Run mocha against one file only. Make sure you do not have a mocha options file which gets included (--opts . ). Reduce the test to an absolute minimum (where is still fails) and post the test and the Price + AbstractPrice code. I assume everything is building if you run tsc?

Comment: what if you remove  "noEmitHelpers" from the tsconfig and run mocha with just the plain --require ts-node/register ?

Comment: tried removing noEmitHelpers, but it doesn't help. Running `tsc` gives no output - is that what is supposed to happen? classes: https://gist.github.com/Burgov/a0ac552ddb55c1035a8bb9dc8e93dd87

Comment: tsc will create js files. Perhaps you should add some include directories in your tsconfig : "include": [    "/common/**/*.ts", .. ] or add the files as arguments to tsc?